# google.maps.geometry not loaded properly sometimes

Tags: google-maps, encoding, geometry

I am using [google encoding libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding) to encode and decode path points array, like below:

To encode:

```
var encodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path);
```

To decode:

```
var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPath);
```

However I found the encoding libraries is not consistently loaded every time. Sometimes the libraries only loads up to maps, as I printed out below:

```
showRouteFor(): google = [object Object]
showRouteFor(): google.maps = [object Object]
showRouteFor(): google.maps.geometry = undefined
```

using the below piece of JS code:

```
console.log("showRouteFor(): google = " + google);
if(google != null) {
    console.log("showRouteFor(): google.maps = " + google.maps);
    if(google.maps != null) {
        console.log("showRouteFor(): google.maps.geometry = " + JSON.stringify(google.maps.geometry));
        if(google.maps.geometry != null) {
            console.log("showRouteFor(): google.maps.geometry.encoding = " + JSON.stringify(google.maps.geometry.encoding));
        }
    }
}
```

Other times the libraries load ok and thus I can use it to decode the path.

What can be the reason? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you load the library by [URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries).

Comment: Thanks. We do load the library by absolute URL while we got this problem.

Comment: Remember to put `libraries` in the url **before** `key` if you're also supplying an API key

Answer (score 1):

`google.maps.geometry` is part of the [geometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) library. If you use it in your code, you should [specify it as a library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries) when you load the Google Maps JavaScript API, for example:

> <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,**geometry**&key=*apikey*" async defer></script>

The confusing part is that other parts of the Google Maps JavaScript API use the geometry library internally. That causes it to still to work for you even you don't specify the library - but only if you happened to have exercised some other functionality, such as DirectionsRenderer, that uses geometry.